# React js rendering link with photo and mount another component after clicking

Tags: reactjs, api, routes, switch-statement

This is my first question here and I'm new :) ,

I have an API and I'm trying to map over it and create a link with a photo so when the user clicks on the photo, I want to render another component with more detail from that post. API is more than 300 items so I need something professional to make it happen

I tried to map route and put it on Switch + map the link which contains photo. Browser will route to the address but another component won't mount or it mounts under main component. I've been trying/looking to fix this issue for more than a week.

thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can share some code here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display details on separate page with different url you can use something like `react-router`. If you need just to show additional details in the same page you can use something like this:

```
class Image extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showDetails: false,
    };

    this.onImageClick = this.onImageClick.bind(this);
  }

  onImageClick() {
    this.setState({ showDetails: true });
  }

  renderDetails() {
    if (!this.state.showDetails) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        Additional details
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.props.src} onClick={this.onImageClick} />
        {this.renderDetails()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ImagesList({ images }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((data) => (
        <Image key={data.someKey} {...data} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but iv tried router too but i dont know how to pass the props to next component by using Route or Link

Comment: @NimaMalaeri you can use parameterized urls for that. You can refer to this example for more information: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params